# Efficient in-memory arrays of hashes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array of some basic objects in JavaScript:

```
[
  {a: 'something', b: 'something else', c: 'other' },
  {a: 'something 2', b: 'something else 2', c: 'other 2' },
  // etc.
]
```

When I reach several hundred thousand of these objects, memory usage is already in the gigabytes under Node.js.  How can I make this more efficient?

- All of the keys are going to be the same for each object, but not necessarily populated in the same order.  I suppose I could translate to an array of arrays, but there is overhead in all the conversion back and forth.
- I know the types of each value in the object ahead of time.

Is there some sort of off-the-shelf in-memory table structure I can use?

I had considered using SQLite3 in-memory but its non-atomic nature prevented me from using it will in my application.  Perhaps there is some native JS alternative so that I could re-use it in browsers as well?

Comment: I think your problem might not be "how do I compress these in memory objects" but rather "how can I store these unused variables outside memory and fetch them when needed". I kinda doubt you need hundreds of thousands of these objects in memory at once. Or am I wrong?

Comment: how about `{a: ['something', 'something 2'], b: ['something else', 'something else 2'], c: [...]}`? That's quite minimal... 1 object, 3 properties, 3 arrays, all the values (can't use "less" than the values take to store)

Comment: @Jan There are definitely ways I can store these outside of the app but that's what I'm trying to avoid. Think of an app that checks a few million URLs for availability. Is a relatively small amount of data with no need for long term storage. Adding a dependency of a small database or similar feels over the top for this task.

Comment: SQLite is .. atomic (the A in ACID), what is that 'non-atomic' bit?

Comment: I don't think it really matters if you need it long term or it should be deleted when you're done with it, requiring a few gigabytes of free clientside memory for such a "small" task as you call it is not so nice towards the user, and makes your app fragile. Unless this is  only run on a production machine with certain guaranteed RAM specs. Just limit the search/execution to one per user, delete the old data when they instigate a new "search" or when the user is logged out, then you can easily implement AJAX pagination of the data or somesuch.

Comment: @user2864740 That's what I thought too, but I ran into all sort of problems with this:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3  If I do an `UPDATE`, subsequent `SELECT`s do not reliably contain the updated data.  (And yes, I'm using the appropriate callbacks and what not.)  Maybe it's just a bug with that package.

Comment: @Jan This isn't a web application.  It has nothing to do with web applications, actually.  Sorry for the confusion.  For my immediate needs, I'm reading several URLs, parsing the data, performing operations on a few million URLs (which I got from the responses in the first few URLs), and outputting status codes to STDOUT.  I was hoping to find a pure JS technique for this sort of thing that I *might* apply to future client-side applications.  Not everyone has a standard CRUD app.

Comment: Oh, well then the same principle applies but without the server-side part: Perform the operations in batches and release the objects from memory as you're done with them.

Comment: @Jan I realize there are ways around this problem, and I am using these techniques today.  I suppose this can be more of an academic exercise than anything.  How to efficiently work with large amounts of structured data in JS.

Comment: I'd say when it comes to holding possibly millions of objects in memory, my suggestion would be: If you can avoid it, don't. :) Other than if your specific purpose is to stress test its capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array which you index using with object boundary of 3 items per object

```
data = ['something', 'something else', 'other', 'something 2', 'something else 2', 'other 2'];

function getObjectAt(index){
 var offset = index * 3;
 return { a : data[offset], b : data[offset + 1],  c : data[offset + 2]};
}
```

The memory footprint should be smaller, of course there are many OTS solutions out there like Redis or hbase.

Comment: Not a bad idea.  I think I will do this.  It's very simple.

Answer (score 2):

"several hundred thousand" is a job for an intelligent paging algorithm server side and backed with a database.

You might load pages of the objects from the server when needed by an ajax call and immediately drop them when unused.

Comment: A variant of that is what I was thinking too.

Comment: I'm not building a web application here.  I was hoping to find a technique that applies to any JS application, but my immediate use case has nothing to do with web applications.  Think of a cron job or similar task.